# Tableau range filter is inclusive?

Tags: tableau-api

It seems to me that the range filter in Tableau is always INCLUSIVE of the end point.  So if I have hourly data and I used the following range

```
From: Jan 1, 12:00 AM
To: Jan 2, 12:00 AM
```

I would actually get 25 data points instead of 24, because the data point corresponding to the end point -- Jan 2, 12:00 AM -- would ALSO be included.

Is there an easy way to switch to use the EXCLUSIVE semantics?

Answer (score 1):

Tableau does not allow you to use exclusive endpoints in the out of the box filter controls. But it's not too hard to work around.

You can either

- adjust the endpoint or
- use parameters to query for input and write a Boolean calculated field to put on the filter shelf

For example, with parameters, you could query for a start day and a positive duration with a slider, and then use datediff() to specify whether to include the record.